# why should we store NPC in pipeline regisger?

Tags: fetch, pipeline

I just touch on `pipeline` theory for a few hours. perhaps it's a easy question, but I really need your help.

I know that we should store `mem[pc]` into `IF/ID` pipeline register in fetch stage for we will decode it in next stage, also we should update `PC` in fetch stage for we will feteh next instruction via that updated `PC` next cycle, but I really don't understand why we should also store NPC into pipeline register.

below is an explanation derived from `Computer Organization and Design`, I don't get it.

`This incremented address is also saved in the IF/ID pipeline register in case it is
needed later for an instruction, such as beq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for saving NPC in the pipeline is because sometimes the next instruction in the pipeline will want to use it.

Look at the definition of `beq`. It has to compute the target address of the branch. Some branches use a fixed location for the target address, like "branch to address A." This is called "branching to an absolute address."

Another kind of branch is a "relative" branch, where the branch target is not an absolute address but an offset, that is, "branch forward X instructions." (If X is negative, this ends up being a backwards branch.) Now consider this: forwards/backwards *from where*? From NPC. That is, for a relative branch instruction, the computation for the new PC value is:

```
NewPC = NPC + X
```

Why do architectures include the ability to perform relative branches? Because it takes less space. Lets say that X has a small value, like 16. The storage required for an absolute branch to a target address is:

```
sizeof(branch opcode) + sizeof(address)
```

But the storage for a relative branch of offset 16 is only:

```
sizeof(branch opcode) + 1     ## number of bytes needed to hold the value 16!
```

Of course, larger offsets can be accommodated by increasing the number of bytes used to hold the offset value. Other kinds of space-saving, range-increasing representations are possible too.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception point is in a branch-delay slot, then one needs two PCs to restart execution: one that
points at the exceptional instruction (delay slot) and another that points at the next instruction. The
second PC is needed because the instruction following the delay slot could be either the next
sequential instruction (if the branch was not taken) or the branch target (if the branch was taken).
Although MIPS has the same issue, it relies on software to back up the exception point to the previous
instruction (when it is a branch) before restarting execution; this works because branches are
idempotent.

Credits: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/courses/cs252-S09/handouts/oldquiz/sp09-quiz1_soln.pdf